# regex for ignoring character if inside () parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I was doing some regex, but I get this bug:

I have this string for example `"+1/(1/10)+(1/30)+1/50"` and I used this regex `/\+.[^\+]*/g`

 and it working fine since it gives me `['+1/(1/10)', '+(1/30)', '+1/50']`

[image]

BUT the real problem is when the `+` is inside the parenthesis `()`

like this: `"+1/(1+10)+(1/30)+1/50"`

[image]

because it will give `['+1/(1', '+10)', '+(1/30)', '+1/50']`

which isn't what I want :(... the thing I want is `['+1/(1+10)', '+(1/30)', '+1/50']`

 so the regex if it see `\(.*\)` skip it like it wasn't there...

*how to ignore in regex?*

---

my code (js):

```js
const tests = {
      correct: "1/(1/10)+(1/30)+1/50",
      wrong  : "1/(1+10)+(1/30)+1/50"
}

function getAdditionArray(string) {
      const REGEX = /\+.[^\+]*/g; // change this to ignore the () even if they have the + sign
      const firstChar = string[0];

      if (firstChar !== "-") string = "+" + string;

      return string.match(REGEX);
}

console.log(
    getAdditionArray(test.correct),
    getAdditionArray(test.wrong),
)
```

Comment: Like this? `\+[^+()]*(?:\([^()]*\))?` https://regex101.com/r/3Yxr01/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude matching parenthesis, and then optionally match `(...)`

```
\+[^+()]*(?:\([^()]*\))?
```

The pattern matches:

- `\+` Match a `+`
- `[^+()]*` Match optional chars other than `+` `(` `)`
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole part

  - `\([^()]*\)` Match from `(...)`
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Yxr01/1).

Another option could be to be more specific about the digits and the `+` and `/` and use a character class to list the allowed characters.

```
\+(?:\d+[+/])?(?:\(\d+[/+]\d+\)|\d+)
```

See another [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8CgNEu/1) demo.

Comment: thanks seems to work fine there, is `(?:` the ignoring thing? thanks is 100% working, I am just curious :)

Comment: @stackdeveloper It is a non capturing group, which you can make optional using the ?